# Angular Cli Reports Invalid Configuration File in Completely Different Directory

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Currently my work files live in
C:\Work\WorkProjects

For a pet project, I have recently created
C:\PetProjects\SomeProject

But when I attempt to run `ng new petproject1` from inside C:\PetProjects\SomeProject I get the error:

```
An invalid configuration file was found ['C:\Work\WorkProjects\path\to\Angular\stuff\angular.json']. Please delete the file before running the command.
```

My workspace configuration for my 'work' files is not in the same directory, so why is the CLI complaining in this instance?

Obviously I cannot delete my angular.json file from within my WorkProjects directory

Comment: Try temporarily renaming it to angular.json.temp

Comment: check the current path of your cmd

Comment: @AdrianBrand this workaround works. I wonder what the heck the Angular Cli could be thinking though...

Comment: Very strange indeed.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, it turns out that because there is a node_modules folder at root path (i.e., C:\node_modules), and that node_modules folder is a symbolic link to another Angular project's node_modules folder (i.e., C:\Work\WorkProjects\path\to\Angular\stuff).

After remove node_modules folder at root path, everything works fine.